# Properly lay out long titles in Part

Tags: fontsize, parts, layout

I can control the size of the font used in my `part` titles.
I can control the location of the word within the page's Y-axis. But for titles that are too long, I get the following ugly result: a big space between (in this example -- see the screen capture) the words "The Long" and "History of Parts".

I'd like to still be able to use a large font size for my part titles, and have these part titles be properly laid out (in this case, with less space between the two lines).

[image]

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%
\usepackage{xcolor} % For links color
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller and quotes small
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{TeX Gyre Heros}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\bfseries\color{black}\filcenter\fontsize{60}{140}\headingfont} % Size of Part
{\Huge\MakeUppercase\headingfont\thepart}
{12pt}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-400pt)$) {\includegraphics{example-image}};}

\begin{document}

\part{The Long History of Parts}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have specified this wide spacing yourself, with `\fontsize{60}{140}`.  the `140` is the baseline-to-baseline distance, and it's more than twice the height of the font.  Reduce this to something like `80` or `100` and you should be happier with the result.

Comment: Oh boy. Thank you. I spent time adjusting those two parameters ... never realizing that the second value was the distance. One reason for my mistake, besides being generally clueless, is that I was trying to get the title centered vertically ... and I got stuck on the assumption that the second value was indeed the Y-axis. But all is well now. All is well.